# SharePoint List auto-increment custom Index

Tags: list, indexing, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint list with 2 different content types (A and B). Now I wanna fill this list with either an Index like: "A-123" or "B-123". A-123 and B-123 are both allowed to exist, but not A-123 twice (or B-123 twice).

the problem is I cant really figure out how to do that in a nice way. Also, I already have many Indexes already filled in, but some are missing (like A-123, A-125, and A-124 is missing or got deleted).

how can I auto-increment both numbers independently? [Excel Visualisation of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoEy4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Microsoft Flow to achieve auto-increment custom Index

**Please following steps:**

1.A SharePoint list with 2 different content types (A and B)

[image]

2.**Integrate** >> **Power Automate** >> **Create a flow**

[image]

3.Create the following Flow

[image]

4.Save and Test Flow

[image]